# common boundary points of connected sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-topology

suppose $A_1, A_2, A_3,\ldots$ are connected closed sets on $\mathbb R^2$ such that for $i, j=1, 2, 3, \ldots$ we have $\operatorname{int}(A_i) \cap \operatorname{int}(A_j)=\varnothing$ and for $i=1, 2, 3, \ldots$ we have $\operatorname{int}(A_i)\ne\varnothing.$

draw $A_1$

draw $A_2$ such that $A_1\cap A_2 \ne \varnothing.$

draw $A_3$ such that $A_1\cap A_2 \ne \varnothing.$ and $A_1\cap A_3 \ne \varnothing.$ and $A_2\cap A_3 \ne \varnothing.$

and so on.

my problem is how many number of sets can be drawn like this

Comment: Draw $n$ different half-lines starting at the origin and you'll get $n$ sets (if $n\ge 2).$

Comment: Why US here? Note that $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 = \emptyset$ is not equivalent to $A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset$.

Comment: no lines allowed, so i need to edit my question

Comment: Do you realize the significance of @GAVD response? If $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$ then $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 = \emptyset$ trivially for all $A_3$. Anyways, the number of sets you can have is unbounded, just keep making the sets smaller as you add more.

Comment: yes it need to be change, sorry my mistake

Comment: Someone has proposed to close this question as unclear, but it's perfectly clear what is being asked.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm not voting to close, but the US map is very confusing here. Does it have anything to do with the actual question?

Comment: @CaveJohnson I saw a math problem that any map can be coloured with 4 colours such that no neighbour countries get same colour, and then i had this problem that's why i entered a map

Answer (score 2):

If two states, $A$ and $B,$ share a boundary, then a road can go from the capital of $A$ to the capital of $B$ without passing through any states besides $A$ and $B$. Now try this with four states mapping the roads between capital cities, between $A$ and $B,$ between $A$ and $C,$ between $A$ and $D,$ between $B$ and $C,$ between $B$ and $D,$ and between $C$ and $D.$
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
A & \leftrightarrow & B & \nwarrow \\
\downarrow & \searrow & \downarrow &  \uparrow \\
C & \leftrightarrow & D & \nearrow \\
& \searrow & \rightarrow
\end{array}
$$
This picture is crude but I hope you can see the road from $C$ to $B.$

A fifth capital city, if connected to $A,$ $B,$ and $C,$ could not reach $D$ without passing through another state.

So five is more than will fit in a plane in this way.

Comment: thanks, can you suggest me some reference books to questions like this

Comment: @sumudumadushan : I think some very elementary books on graph theory, such as that of Robin J. Wilson, give an account of this, under the concept of "planar" graphs.