# The number of boundaries among $n$ states?

Tags: plane-geometry, planar-graphs, geometric-probability

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467746/common-boundary-points-of-connected-sets) inspires another:

With **four** states in proximity to each other one often sees **five** boundaries between states; for example:
$$
\begin{array}{rc}
1 &\text{New York}/\text{Vermont} \\
2 &\text{New York}/\text{Massachusets} \\
3 & \text{New York}/\text{Connecticut} \\
4 & \text{Connecticut}/\text{Massachusetts} \\
5 & \text{Massachusetts}/\text{Vermont} \\  \\
&\text{but not Vermont}/\text{Connecticut}
\end{array}
$$
With **four** states one can see **six** boundaries only if one of them is surrounded by the other three.

With **five** states in contiguity, the smallest number of boundaries you can have is four; and the largest is less than ten even though there are ten unordered pairs, because they must lie in a plain.

With $n$ states, the smallest is $n-1.$

- With $n$ states, what is the largest number of state boundaries you can have? (Taking each state to be a connected set in the plane.)
- Is there any sense in which it makes sense to ask about an average number, choosing the boundaries of states in some random way?
- Is this function of $n$ found in OEIS?

Comment: How do you define "boundary" - and how do you count them? Examples: (1) a four-corners situation (take a 2x2 checker board); two "states" have exactly one POINT in common. Is that a border? (2) Two states may have two DISCONNECTED pieces of border with each other; is that one border or two?

Comment: @mathguy : I want the boundary to be a $1$-dimensional curve in the plane, and each such curve to separate just two states (so nothing from any book titled _Counterexamples in Whatever_).

Comment: OK. And I assume you still count a single boundary (between two given states) even if that curve is disconnected (think the border between China and Russia going around Mongolia... the Russia-China border is at least two separate connected components).

Answer (score 2):

Assume all your states are connected, and consider the dual graph: vertices are the states, and edges connect states the share a border. You're in effect asking for the largest number of edges possible in a planar graph with $n$ vertices, which turns out to be $3(n-2)$. (In short, planarity requires that $V - E + F = 2$, and counting the edges around a face gives $E\geq \frac{3}{2}F$. There's a straightforward example in the other direction.) As for randomization, there is an entire field known as random graph theory that addresses this kind of problem.

Comment: ok, That would be the maximum; now lets ask about the average. Say a Poisson process in the plane locates the capital cities, and the Delaunay triangulation connects capitals of neighboring states. Among these infinitely many capital cities on this infinite flat Earth, we consider whether we can defined such a thing as an average connected set of $n$ capital cities. Then we would be asking about the average number of edges. However, what I've seen called "random graph theory" doesn't consider the vertices to be in a Euclidean plane or any other sort of space with a geometric structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know very little about random graph theory, and the applications I've seen of it are very specialized.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Shoot, sorry, I was answering another question in a different window and mixed you up with the newbie who was answering that question. My experience with random graph theory is only in the context of combinatorial group theory, mostly scavenged from random group theory. In particular, I'm not familiar with way of dealing with planarity (which is crucial here), but I'd set up the problem by considering $K_n$ with edges turn on or off according to some i.i.d. random variables (fairly low to promote planarity, since you have to avoid any $K_{3, 3}$ or $K_5$)...

Comment: ...Since the bound above just comes from the fact that any region in the (simple) graph has to be bounded by at least three edges, you might be able to approximate the optimal number of edges by considering something like the average degree in the original graph, which is conveniently easy to compute. Not sure if that's actually useful, but it's where I'd start if I were going into the problem blind.